# ArchLinux Qt eglfs

Tags: archlinux, c++, opengles, qt

here is what I did.

I updated everything to latest, than I installed Qt5 and some related packages:

```
pacman -S gcc make qt5-base qt5-declarative qt5-imageformats qt5-multimedia qt5-quickcontrols qt5-script qt5-svg qt5-tools qt5-webkit qt5-xmlpatterns python python-pyqt5
```

than I downloaded [mlbrowser for Rasbian](https://github.com/Topguy/mlbrowser) source code (downloaded to desktop, copied by scp) and ran:

```
qmake DEFINES+=_BROWSER_ DEFINES+=_MOUSE_ DEFINES+=_PROPERTYCHANGER_ ../src/mlbrowser.pro
make
```

just as I was instructed in `readme.md`.

Everything compiles just fine, and even runs if executed like this:

```
./mlbrowser -platform linuxfb http://www.raspberry.org
```

but if I run mlbrowser like this:

```
./mlbrowser -platform eglfs http://www.raspberry.org
```

I get the following error:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "eglfs".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, kms, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

which is nonsense, because eglfs is listed as available. Also the following command:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/
```

gives me the following list

```
total 1452
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 249820 May 27 22:01 libqeglfs.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 216844 May 27 22:01 libqkms.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 154872 May 27 22:01 libqlinuxfb.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  30520 May 27 22:01 libqminimal.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 134188 May 27 22:01 libqminimalegl.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 100920 May 27 22:01 libqoffscreen.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 593160 May 27 22:01 libqxcb.so[/code]
```

so libqeglfs.so actually exists and is executable.

How can I debug this error? What tools should I use in this case? Or maybe this is a known issue with known solution I just was not able to find?

P.S. I've just found out that:

- with minimalegl platform application terminates with the following error:

  ```
  Opened display 0xcdf6a0

  libEGL warning: DRI2: xcb_connect failed  
  libEGL warning: DRI2: xcb_connect failed  
  Could not initialize egl display

  EGL error
  Aborted (core dumped)
  ```
- with linuxfb platform keyboard input is completely ignored.

Not sure if this is relevant, since I need eglfs.

Answer (score 1):

## Link GPU eglfs binaries so Qt can get to them in system path

```
sudo ln -s /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so.1.0.0
sudo ln -s /opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
```

## Install the leandog apt server in your sources

```
echo "deb http://apt.leandog.com/ jessie main" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys BDCBFB15
```

## Install packages

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ci-train-ppa-service/landing-011
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-raspi2/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:a-j-buxton/qt5-raspi-eglfs
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libraspberrypi-dev
```

cd /usr/lib

```
sudo ln -s libGLESv2.so libGLESv2.so.2
```

Install your desired Qt libraries and modules.

Run your app with arguments: `-platform eglfs`